# Accessing PHP object variables from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a PHP class object called Datapoints stored in session and I am trying to access a variable from it in a javascript function.

From within the javascript I can access session variables through $_SESSION['foo'], but I can't access the object variables. I've tried all sorts of syntax to return the variable.

I can access variables like this, and it works fine.

```
<?php echo intval($_SESSION['count']); ?>
```

but I would rather have the whole object in session, for example if I do this...

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/javascript");  
    session_start();  
    $c = $_SESSION['datapoints']->count;
    $c1 = $datapoints->count;
?>  
var count = <?php echo $c; ?>
var count1 = <?php echo $c1; ?>
```

Both return null.

My object looks like this through print_r('datapoints').

```
Datapoints Object ( [startdate] => 2013-06-05 [currency] => GBP [count] => 4527 [datapoints] => Array ( [0] => Datapoint Object (...) ... ))
```

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks for your help, I've solved this now. Turns out it was a problem with the autoloader not loading classes properly from within the javascript files.

Comment: You can't access PHP values directly in JavaScript.  You can, however, *emit* values to JavaScript using PHP code.  There's no difference in how you'd do this between session variables vs. objects.  How are you attempting this and in what way does it not work as expected?  Instead of describing your code, actually show your code.

Comment: Your $_SESSION['datapoints'] is an array try $_SESSION['datapoints'][0]->count;

Comment: Tried that too, unfortunately not working.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've solved this now. Turns out it was a problem with the autoloader not loading classes properly from within the javascript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIRST LINE

```
@session_start();
```

use "echo"

```
var startdate = "<? echo urObject->startdate?>";
```

Comment: but the object is empty or not?

Comment: I have the session start and the object is there.

Comment: what show echo $_SESSION['datapoints']->count; immediately after session_start()? also null?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN access PHP variables in javascript. It's simple:

```
    var whatever = "<?php echo your_php_variable ?>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already am using that, the problem is when the object is in session I cannot access the object variables. In your example, if I do `var whatever = "<?php echo datapoints->count; ?>";` it returns null.